# Is the drop rate constant for bosses?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I farm King Leoric over and over again, will I get the same drop rates every time? Or is there some kind of reductions on the drops after the first time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first time you kill a boss on Normal you have a higher chance of getting better items than any subsequent kill.  Later difficulties and kills have a lowered chance.

http://www.diablo3farming.com/2012/04/16/droprates-on-bosses-discussed-in-d3-beta/

Answer (score 1):

"Later difficulties and kills have a lowered chance." I would also like to point out not just lowered but very, very low.

Myself and 3 other people cleared Nightmare setting and combined in total for all bosses (so effectivly loot from 4 full runs) we got 2 Yellow items 0 Gold 0 Green. We ofc got some yellows from champion mobs etc but bosses seem to have a lower drop rate than champions mobs. Got more chance getting yellows from rock piles than you do from bosses.